# Display more than one image at onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have the following code which displays an image onmouseover and sets back the default image active onmouseout.

```
<img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='image2.jp'" onmouseout="this.src='image1.jpg'" />
```

I want to be able to display multiple images `onmouseover` event; each displaying after a set time. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: How would you display multiple images on mouse-over when you have only a single mouse, and a single image you can mouse over?

Comment: do you want to disable all images if one is hovered or only the one that is hovered

Comment: Look into JavaScript event handling, rather than inline `onmouse~` attributes.

Comment: Just like an array of images displaying each after some seconds
@tikider Like having products listed (Eg Clothes) and you hover on any, it displays the side and back views or more images.

Comment: @OmniPotens, so when you hover on a main image a set of secondary images have to be shown?

Comment: @tikider Yes, that's my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <img id="initialIMG" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/bonecrusher-icon.png" />
</div>

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/bonecrusher-icon.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/longhaul-icon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/bonecrusher-icon.png'" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").mouseenter(function() {  
        var t = setTimeout(function(){ 
           $("#initialIMG").hide();

           $("#initialIMG").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/longhaul-icon.png" )
           $("#initialIMG").fadeIn(50);
           $("#container").append( '<img id="addedIMG" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/mixmaster-icon.png" style="display:none;"/>' );      
           $("#addedIMG").fadeIn(50);  
        },500);
    });
    $("#container").mouseleave(function() {
          var t = setTimeout(function(){ 
              $("#initialIMG").hide();                      
              $("#initialIMG").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jamespeng/construction/128/bonecrusher-icon.png" )
              $("#initialIMG").fadeIn(50);   
              $("#addedIMG").remove();
              },500);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HNLNX/3/)

Comment: Does this have a settimeout for each image? Please I omitted that in my question.

Comment: You could add a timeout with javascript setTimeout() function

Comment: Please can you update your solution with it as I know I needed to have "setTimeout" there but don't know how to integrate it

Comment: This works, thanks but it doesn't not like I want it. Just like the normal onmouseover and another image fades in, same way is how I want this too to function. Any leads?

Comment: Cool one @Alex Art. How do I get this to work exactly how an onmouseover event displays images when hovered over? The speed of display is fast too and there's no longer the setTimeout to control it.

Comment: Okay. I'm here and following your processes as you edit. Let me test this last edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38421/discussion-between-alex-art-and-omnipotens)

Comment: are you available? I'll like to ask some questions with regards this solution you helped me with here.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution, maybe not the most beautiful one, but it works.

HTML:

```
<img id="image1" src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="showImages()" onmouseout="hideImages()" />
<img id="image2" src="image2.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img id="image3" src="image3.jpg" style="display:none;" />
```

Javascript:

```
function showImages(){
  document.getElementById('image2').style = '';
  document.getElementById('image3').style = '';
}
function hideImages(){
  document.getElementById('image2').style = 'display: none;';
  document.getElementById('image3').style = 'display: none;';
}
```

Of course you should solve this with classes to clean up your code. This is just a basic example that works.

Comment: This just displays an image onmouseover but I want to hover a set of images like up to 3 or 4 images onmouseover

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showImage() {
    //Your code here
}

function hideImage() {
    //Your code here
}

<img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage();" onmouseout="hideImage();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific  reason you don't want to use jQuery?

in css:

```
#my-pics .default{
    display: inline;
}
```

in html:

```
<div id="my-pics">
    <img src="image1.jpg" class="default" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" style="display:none;" />
    <img src="image3.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

in js:

```
$("#my-pics").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".default").hide();
    $(this).find(":not(.default)").show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".default").show();
    $(this).find(":not(.default)").hide();
});
```

Of course you need to import jquery first. Haven't tested this myself, any errors?

**CSS solution?**

in html:

```
<div id="my-pics">
    <img src="image1.jpg" class="default" />
    <img src="image2.jpg"/>
    <img src="image3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

in css:

```
#my-pics img{
    display: none;
}
#my-pics img.default{
    display: inline;
}
#my-pics:hover img{
    display: inline;
}
#my-pics:hover img.default{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then when your document is ready:

```
<img class="main-image" data-target=".images-set1" src="mainImage1.jpg">
```

secondary images:

```
<div class="images-set1">
    <img src="secondary1-1.jpg" style="display:none">
    <img src="secondary1-2.jpg" style="display:none">
    <img src="secondary1-2.jpg" style="display:none">
    ....
</div>
```

with jQuery:

```
$('main-image').on('mouseover', function (event) {
    $($(event.target).attr('data-target') + ' img').show();
})
.on('mouseout', function (event) {
    $($(event.target).attr('data-target') + ' img').hide();
});
```

this will just hide/show the secondary image element related to the main image,
tell me if this is not exactly the behaviour you want.

Comment: I sure can't get this to work. Anything missing? I sure included JQuery 1.9 to fire the JS.

Comment: this code is just showcasing a solution, you need to adapt it not just copy/past it. Or you can include your own code with more details so that we can help you.

Comment: you should try to debug it. for example put some console.log inside the events handlers to see if they get fired or not.

Comment: Alright. I will try it out to see what I can make out of it. Thanks for the lead