# Why does the 'onmouseover' keyword change another targets in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I run it on Chrome

My problem -
After the mouse touches all the images, even if `onmouseout` from one image, all images change at the same time

I do not understand why this is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYL3x.gif" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht3Jw.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmBrB.gif'">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYL3x.gif" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht3Jw.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmBrB.gif'">

</body>
</html>
```

Image Source info

artist:Sevarihk

Original:https://opengameart.org/content/animated-bamboo-door-sprite

```
[dor_1.gif][1]
[door_1_close.gif][2]
[door_1_open.gif][3]
```

Comment: hope this answer will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114469/6108882
or add some more details in your question

Comment: When I happen about this situation I always try to listen to the event trigger using console.log() https://codepen.io/agokselb/pen/BarbMme

Comment: I have tried reproduce your code here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/GRxezQz but would like to know more about your issue.

Comment: +)I don't know why, but the problem only occurs when it is gif
When it's png, not use console.log()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both `<img>` represent the same and only internal gif image. When you do set the `<img>`'s `src` to that URL again, the gif animation is reloaded, [as per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#restart-the-animation). But it is reloaded for all instances of this image.
You can avoid that by tricking the browser in thinking both images are separate, e.g by appending a query-param to the URL:

(Notice the `?A` and `?B` I added at the end of the URL in the `mouseout` event handlers).

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYL3x.gif" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht3Jw.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmBrB.gif?A'">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYL3x.gif" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht3Jw.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmBrB.gif?B'">
```

But this means the image is actually loaded twice...

Comment: Does '!a' or '@a' not work but '?a' works, can you explain what '?' is?

Comment: It's a "query-param", a.k.a "search param", a.k.a ["query string"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). That's a way to communicate to the server and make it return different values based on it without having to setup a new end point. So for what the browser knows, `/img.gif?A` and `/img.gif?B` could return completely different responses, and thus it can't cache both as being the same *image*. But here we passed query strings that the server doesn't know about and will just ignore.